# How to update text in RecyclerView every second?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having **RecyclerView** which shows **ArrayList** items inside of a **Fragment**.

Items have a string which is necessary to update every second.

How do I update a string in all **ArrayList** items every second and display changes immediately in **RecyclerView**?

**Fragment** where **RecyclerView** is displayed:

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment{

    DbActivity db;
    Cursor fullData;

    View v;

    ConstraintLayout addDeadline;
    CardView empty;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Deadline> deadlines;
    DeadlineAdapter deadlineAdapter;

    String id, summary, date, time, deadline, labels;

    public RecyclerViewFragment() { // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_view, container, false);

        setBasicView();
        addDeadline();

        return v;
    }

    public void setBasicView(){
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        empty = v.findViewById(R.id.empty);

        db = new DbActivity(getContext());
        fullData = db.getAllData();
        if (fullData.getCount() > 0){
            if (fullData.moveToFirst()) {
                deadlines = new ArrayList<>();
                int i = 1;
                do {
                    String check = fullData.getString(5);
                    if (!check.startsWith("co")){
                        id = fullData.getString(1);
                        summary = fullData.getString(2);
                        date = fullData.getString(3);
                        time = fullData.getString(4);
                        deadline = fullData.getString(5);
                        labels = fullData.getString(6);
                        deadlines.add(new Deadline(id, summary, date, time, deadline,
                                labels));
                        i++;
                    }
                } while (fullData.moveToNext());
            }
            empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            deadlines = new ArrayList<>();
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        deadlineAdapter = new DeadlineAdapter(getContext(), deadlines);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(deadlineAdapter);
    }

    public void addDeadline(){
        addDeadline = v.findViewById(R.id.add_deadline);
        addDeadline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getContext(), AddDeadlineActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Codes.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("AddDeadline"));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            DbActivity db = new DbActivity(getContext());
            Cursor newDeadline = db.getAllData();
            int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1);
            try {
                if (position != -1){
                    newDeadline.moveToPosition(position);
                    id = newDeadline.getString(1);
                    summary = newDeadline.getString(2);
                    date = newDeadline.getString(3);
                    time = newDeadline.getString(4);
                    deadline = newDeadline.getString(5);
                    labels = newDeadline.getString(6);
                    deadlines.remove(position);
                    deadlines.add(position, new Deadline(String.valueOf(position), summary, date, time, deadline, labels));
                }
                else {
                    newDeadline.moveToLast();
                    id = newDeadline.getString(1);
                    summary = newDeadline.getString(2);
                    date = newDeadline.getString(3);
                    time = newDeadline.getString(4);
                    deadline = newDeadline.getString(5);
                    labels = newDeadline.getString(6);
                    deadlines.add(new Deadline(id, summary, date, time, deadline, labels));
                }
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                newDeadline.moveToLast();
            }
            deadlineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**Custom Adapter**:

```
public class DeadlineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DeadlineAdapter.mViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<Deadline> deadlines;

    public DeadlineAdapter(Context context, List<Deadline> deadlines) {
        this.context = context;
        this.deadlines = deadlines;
    }

    @Override
    public mViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new mViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final mViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.summary.setText(deadlines.get(position).getSummary());
        holder.deadline.setText(deadlines.get(position).getDeadline());
        holder.labels.setText(String.valueOf(deadlines.get(position).getLabels()));

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                editDeadline(position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void editDeadline(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddDeadlineActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", deadlines.get(position).getId());
        intent.putExtra("summary", deadlines.get(position).getSummary());
        intent.putExtra("date", deadlines.get(position).getDate());
        intent.putExtra("time", deadlines.get(position).getTime());
        intent.putExtra("labels", deadlines.get(position).getLabels());
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return deadlines.size();
    }

    public static class mViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        private TextView summary;
        private TextView deadline;
        private TextView labels;

        public mViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            summary = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customSummary);
            deadline = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customDeadline);
            labels = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customLabels);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        }

        public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
            this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), true);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you should use `Timer` in android . `Timer` with 1 second repeat . write a function in RecyclerViewAdapter for update text and then `notifydatasetchanged`

Comment: @mhsankar Thanks, I'll find out how to do this correctly and then try

Comment: if you cant solve this . give me your email Address.

Comment: @mhsankar You can find it in my profile. Thank you for trying to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.

Firstly we need to create a method inside of our custom adapter which will change data of all items of the list.

1 step. For example,

```
public void timer() {
    String stringToChange;
    for(int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++) {
        //change data depending on time

        //set new data to the deadline field
        yourList.get(i).setData(stringToChange);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Then we should create a Handler inside of a fragment or an activity where list is located.

2 step example:

```
public void setHandler(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 1000 ; //1000 milliseconds = 1 sec

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            customAdapter.timer(); // call our adapter method here
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

3 step is to call setHandler method inside of OnCreate (OnCreateView for fragments) method:

```
setHandler();
```

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` will force reinflate every view holder on screen. That's the worst you can do if you need to update one text view in each item. And it happens every second. At least `notifyItemRangeChanged` with payload, please.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Sounds reasonable. It's just the way I have found. I refuse of updating every second in my app